# XCode 5 update breaks the storyboard scenes layout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

As the title said :  as soon as I've installed the new XCode version from the MacAppStore (XCode 5), 
my storyboard is broken : meaning a lot a views have got wrong coordinates and wrong size.
(negative values , or zero values...)

I'll have a lot of work to do to fix this.

So the question is,  does anyone has experience the same bug? Is there a way to avoid that ? and more important (even if I don't believe it) is there a way to fix my existing file ?

Comment: It sounds like your issues are with the new iOS 7 layouts, not with Xcode 5 itself.

Comment: Did you use autolayout ?

Comment: I didn't use auto layout.   And yes it may be an issue from IOS7 layout but this update isn't coming with the XCode 5 update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK  so finally didn't find any perfect answer yet  I'll be glad to accept another answer if we find one.

the things I had to do is check on each broken view the '`autosizing`' setting in **view inspector** :  when it's no properly set. 
( as with unproper setting such as,  "kept same space on left" and "keep same space on right" and "don't resize when your parent resize" => impossible )
Then IOS 7 doesn't get de same result as IOS6,  but its not an important matter since this result were unpredictable anyway. (so its still unpredictable on ios7 ^^)

I could fix some issues by fixing those autosizing settings.

But for the other views where the coords were negative or zero sized...   just fixed it by hand...

( Actually, I didn't have to do it, because someone else in my office took care of it, thanks a lot to him => my answer could be "find someone to fix it by hand for you" XD )

Anyway, thank you Apple for this update.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the exact same issue, whats worse is my map view renders black, one of my pages doesn't render any items at all for no apparent reason and various items are sat in different places on the screen due to the IOS 7 changes.

After eventually getting the IOS 6 simulator to work. The storyboard now appears broken for that version too (black view for mapview etc) objects misaligned etc.

This is a pain!

EDIT:

In the view controller under the Attribute Inspector unticking the following tabs will reset your layout without you having to adjust anything:

Extend Edges:

Under top bars
Under bottom bars

Also if you find you have lost some menus or they are black (like my uimapview) check it's x and y co-ords and it's size. Mine were completely broken at X:-2137 and Y:865 and size of X: 0 and y:0

Comment: thanks for your  answer,  unfortnatly unticking Extend Edges:

"Under top bars" / "Under bottom bars" didn't help :/   I've experienced the exact same break with X:-2137 and Y:865 and size of X: 0 and y:0. I'm afraid I have to fix every broken coord by hand :(